# Pandas data frame creation inconsistencies

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I was creating a pandas dataframe from a python dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

obs_dict = {
            'pos':[[0,0],[10,10]],
            'vel':[[0,0],[0,0]],
            'mass':np.array([10000,10000])
           }

print pd.DataFrame(obs_dict)
```

Returns:

```
    mass       pos     vel
0  10000    [0, 0]  [0, 0]
1  10000  [10, 10]  [0, 0]
```

Notice that I have a 2d list as a items in the position ('pos') and velocity ('vel') column. However when I replace the 2d list with a 2d numpy array:

```
obs_dict = {
            'pos':np.array([[0,0],[10,10]]),
            'vel':np.array([[0,0],[0,0]]),
            'mass':np.array([10000,10000])
           }
```

I get an exception:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Unfortunately the data that I am using is contained within a numpy array and I don't want to convert it to a python list, is there any way to make this work?

Comment: a list of lists is not the same as a 2d numpy array, I imagine you would need `np.array([[0,0],[10,10]]).tolist()` to get the same behaviour as the list

Comment: What are you hoping to store as the column values? Basically it won't work trying to store 2-D arrays as this as the ctor will check the dimensions as you've found, the following works but I don't know if that's what you want:`obs_dict = {
            'pos':[np.array([[0,0],[10,10]])],
            'vel':[np.array([[0,0],[0,0]])],
            'mass':[np.array([10000,10000])]
           }`

Comment: @EdChum This results in only one row, I want two rows (one for each position, velocity and mass)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham This is just a test case, the real code will have upwards of 10000 velocities, masses and positions so tolist() will be a major slowdown

Comment: but the dimensions of your `mass` array is a 1-D array not a 2-D array, whilst the other arrays are 2-D so are you intending to store np arrays of different dimensions in each column?, I think you'd have to extract the components of each x/y component of your pos and vel in order for this to work

Comment: After trying a few hacks this I don't think this can be done, I've never seen a series storing multi-dimensional np arrays, I've only ever seen separate columns for the components of the 2-d array, so I suggest you look at that as a structure

Comment: I think you might be wrong about the source of a "major slowdown".  Putting objects (lists, arrays, whatever) into columns rather than core number types (floats, ints) is likely to cause you bigger problems than a one time conversion of an array to a list.  You almost always are better off having a row with 5 floats rather than 1 float and 2 lists.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
obs_dict = {
        'pos':[[0,0],[10,10]],
        'vel':[[0,0],[0,0]],
        'mass':np.array([10000,10000])
       }
print pd.DataFrame(obs_dict)`
```

you just got a dataframe with some object columns, try dtypes:

```
tt = pd.DataFrame(obs_dict)
tt.dtypes
```

shows:

```
mass     int64
pos     object
vel     object
dtype: object
```

I don't think this can be done.